# Flagging modal is hidden/obstructed on mobile view

Tags: bug, design

I'm experiencing a ui/ux bug when using WPSE on my phone, using the mobile view of this site. Whenever I try to flag a question, the modal ends up being hidden behind the answer textarea or answering section.

This only happens on the 2nd and 3rd panels of the flagging process, the first step is always fine. I'm unable to state why sometimes it happens on the 2nd panel, and then other times it's only on the third.

If it happens on the 2nd step then I lose the entire bottom half of the flagging modal under the commenting area, if it's the third stage than only the answer textarea obscures the modal.

When it's hidden behind the entire answer area I can't complete any actions, when it's just the texarea sitting infront of the modal I still can't complete an action as the focus is always on the textarea.

Should be noted this only happens on questions that have little or no answers/comments. If there is enough distance between the question and the answer area I do not ave this issue.

I am visiting the site on my Samsung Galaxy Note II using the default android browser. Below is a picture of what happens if it fails on the 2nd panel:

[image: Obstructed view of the flagging modal]